# Android Toolbar Button Error - ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

Tags: java, android

I want to create a button in the toolbar instead of and icon and have come this far. I know I need to create an OnClickListener but can't pull it off. Everything I try results in an error

> ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN

This is my **menu_home_activity.xml** file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.getmore.getmoreplus.activity.HomeActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_call"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/callicon"
        android:title=" "
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
</menu>
```

and my **callicon.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/callbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/call" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and finally my **HomeFragment.java** file

```
  @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    //Creates options in the top bar
    //Currently only creates the phone
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_activity, menu);
           super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Sorry still a novice at programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I fixed it.

I added this to my activity class

```
private ImageView callbutton;
```

I then added a listener to the int() section. **WORKING**

```
callbutton = (ImageView)mRootView.findViewById(R.id.callbtn);
    callbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //my action

        }
    });
```

So simple but for a novice like it takes a bit longer to work out.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to give an onclick listner to the toolbar icon, the same functionality can be acheived through

```
onOptionsItemSelected()
```

First instead of `app:actionLayout="@layout/callicon"` in the menu xml you can directly give the icon like this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.getmore.getmoreplus.activity.HomeActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_call"
    android:title="Call"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@drawable/call"/>
```

In your activity,

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_activity, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Then this,

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_call) {
        // Do your onClick action here
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

I think that solves your problem

Comment: Thanks - however unfortunately if I use android:icon="@drawable/call I can't change the size of the menu icon. e.g. have a button that 100 x 40